# VSCode debugging with libvala-0.36 needs debug symbols?

Tags: vala

Developing a Vala (libvala) program using --pkg libvala-0.36 on VSCode 1.12.2/Linux Mint 18. Running an F5 Debug session, I'm able to set breakpoints and see local variable values. But I can't seem to get Vala objects to display class data instead of just an address. For example:

```
foreach (Vala.SourceFile src in context.get_source_files ()) {
                   var source = find_source_file (src.filename) ;
```

The Debug window (and mouse hover) displays src:Object@#*0x660aa0 instead of a Vala.SourceFile class object.  I'm guessing there is no libvala symbol table loaded? "apt search" shows libvala-0.36-0-dbg and libvala-0.36-dev packages installed, but not sure how to use them.

Googling, I found a reference to "valac-dbgsym". So I tried...

```
sudo apt-get install valac-dbgsym
E: Unable to locate package valac-dbgsym
```

Appreciate your help/insight on what i'm doing wrong. My objective is to Run Debug and display Vala.??? class object data in Debug window.
Thanks for your help!

```
george@george-KT369AA-ABA-a6512p ~ $ sudo apt search libvala
p   libvala-0.30-0                  - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.30-0:i386             - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.30-0-dbg              - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.30-0-dbg:i386         - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.30-dev                - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.30-dev:i386           - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.34-0                  - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.34-0:i386             - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.34-0-dbg              - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.34-0-dbg:i386         - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.34-dev                - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.34-dev:i386           - C# like language for the GObject system - 
i   libvala-0.36-0                  - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.36-0:i386             - C# like language for the GObject system - 
i   libvala-0.36-0-dbg              - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.36-0-dbg:i386         - C# like language for the GObject system - 
i   libvala-0.36-dev                - C# like language for the GObject system - 
p   libvala-0.36-dev:i386           - C# like language for the GObject system - 
v   libvala-dev                     -                                           
v   libvala-dev:i386                -                                           
p   libvaladoc-data                 - API documentation generator for vala (data
v   libvaladoc-data:i386            -                                           
p   libvaladoc-dev                  - API documentation generator for vala (deve
p   libvaladoc-dev:i386             - API documentation generator for vala (deve
p   libvaladoc3                     - API documentation generator for vala (libr
p   libvaladoc3:i386                - API documentation generator for vala (libr

===========================================================================
----------building CSharp2Vala.exe
===========================================================================
valac -X -I/media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/vala-extra-vapis/ --verbose --vapidir=/media/george/SharedData/P
rojects/Vala/osslibs/ --girdir=/media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/osslibs/ --pkg gio-2.0 --define=DEBUG --save
-temps -g -X -w \
        --pkg libvala-0.36  \
        --pkg gee-0.8 \
        -X -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="..." \
        -X -I/media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/Echo-src/lib \
        -X /media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/Echo-src/lib/libecho.so \
        /media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/Echo-src/lib/libecho.vapi \
        /media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/CSharp2Vala.vala \        -o /media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/CSharp2Vala.exe
Loaded package `/usr/share/vala-0.36/vapi/glib-2.0.vapi'
Loaded package `/usr/share/vala-0.36/vapi/gobject-2.0.vapi'
Loaded package `/usr/share/vala-0.36/vapi/gio-2.0.vapi'
Loaded package `/usr/share/vala-0.36/vapi/libvala-0.36.vapi'
Loaded package `/usr/share/vala/vapi/gee-0.8.vapi'

cc -g -o '/media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/CSharp2Vala.exe' '/media/george/SharedData/Projects/V
    ala/CSharp2Vala/CSharp2Vala.c' -pthread -I/usr/include/vala-0.36 -I/usr/include/gee-0.8 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgio-2.0 -lvala-0.36 -lgee-0.8 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 '-I/media/geor
    ge/SharedData/Projects/Vala/vala-extra-vapis/' '-w' '-DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=...' '-I/media/george/SharedData/Projects/V
    ala/CSharp2Vala/Echo-src/lib' '/media/george/SharedData/Projects/Vala/CSharp2Vala/Echo-src/lib/libecho.so'
    Compilation succeeded - 3 warning(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `libvala` is an internal API used by clients such as `valac` and `vapigen`. Both of those clients are developed in the main source and so are kept in sync with the `libvala` API. The API isn't changing much, but for example, with the upcoming 0.38 release [commit c9aa47](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/commit/?id=c9aa4716b2645af40080bd6523065e78fceba3b4) removes the CCode and Codegen symbols from the API, making them private to `libvala` only. Also [commit     e1b399](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/commit/?id=e1b399b332dbf0875b6de8499f31877db6f9f3a1) will add an optional parameter to `Report.set_colors`. Over the years, however, a number of IDE tools have started to use `libvala` directly. So the pragmatic advice would be to avoid the `libvala` API if you can and to use as little of the API as possible if you have to. Typically use the part of the API that is used by existing tools.

If you are looking to develop `libvala` itself then you can build Vala with the `--enable-coverage` when you configure the Autotools build. This will add line numbers for Vala source files in `libvala` and so show the Vala source and line number in backtraces. You will also want to install `GLib` debug symbols. I think this is `libglib2.0-0-dbgsym` in Ubuntu.

If you are looking to debug Vala programs. Then the `--debug` switch for `valac` will add the source file and line number to the final binary. BTW `--debug` is the default when using [Meson build with Vala](http://mesonbuild.com/Vala). The type system in Vala is based on GLib so will want the GLib2 debug symbols installed as well.

Comment: Compiling CSharp2Vala.exe using --pkg libvala-0.36 and the --debug option, has always worked. Displaying program variable values with dbg is not a problem. Debugging values of a variable typed from a libvala class without libvala symbols is the issue.
I've tried compiling with ---pkg libvala-0.36-0-dev and  ---pkg libvala-0.36-0-dbg, but both error with missing .vapi files. The pass week has been futile trying to find docs or examples showing how to compile with these packages.